# The node js router server is not updating the code and giving same result everytime

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, visual-studio

i am making a twitter clone. I used 2 api to put comments and retweets. Both of them are same in code and will give similar response. When i wrote the retweet api i forgot to get fullName in the populate function However how many times i change the code the result is showing the same result that i wrote the first time. The code for get comments and retweet is same but i can't get fullName in retweet function

Here is the router file where i have written code for APIs

Post Route.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const PostModel = mongoose.model("TwitterPostModel");
const protectedRoute = require("../middleware/protectedResource");

const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

/*assuming an express app is declared here*/
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

router.put("/retweets" , protectedRoute , (req , res)=> {
    const retweeter = {retweetedBy : req.user._id}
    PostModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.postId , {
        $push : {retweeter : retweeter}
    }, {
        new: true
    }).populate("retweeter.retweetedBy" , " _id fullName email")
      .populate("retweeter._id" , " _id email fullName")
      .exec((error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: error });
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    })
})

router.put("/comment", protectedRoute, (req, res) => {

    const comment = { commentText: req.body.commentText, commentedBy: req.user._id }

    PostModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.postId, {
        $push: { comments: comment }
    }, {
        new: true //returns updated record
    }).populate("comments.commentedBy", "_id email ") //comment owner
        .populate("author", "_id fullName")// post owner
        .exec((error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: error });
            } else {
                res.json(result);
            }
        })
});
```

This is the post schema. The fields for comment and retweet are taking same data in API.

Post Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const postSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    description:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    location:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    likes:[
        {
            type:ObjectId,
            ref: "TwitterUserModel"
        }
    ],
    retweeter:[
        {
            retweetedBy: { type:ObjectId,
            ref: "TwitterUserModel"} 
        }
    ],
    comments:[
        {
            commentedBy: { type:ObjectId,
            ref: "TwitterUserModel"}
        }
    ],
    image:{
        type: String,
        default:'https://pngtree.com/freebackground/builder-posing-in-photo-studio-3d-realistic_2615197.html'
    },
    author:{
        type:ObjectId,
        ref : "TwitterUserModel"
    },
});

mongoose.model("TwitterPostModel" , postSchema)
```

This is the mongoDB compass data stored by APIs. The data stored in comments and retweets is same.

```
/** 
* Paste one or more documents here
*/
{
  "description": "Good Coffee",
  "location": "Paris",
  "likes": [
    {
      "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
    }
  ],
  "image": "http://localhost:4000/files/undefined",
  "author": {
    "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
  },
  "comments": [
    {
      "commentText": "Nice",
      "commentedBy": {
        "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "657315f8442df8f74f349ae5"
      }
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0,
  "retweeter": [
    {
      "retweetedBy": {
        "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "65743c63ef46fb87f50713ea"
      }
    },
    {
      "retweetedBy": {
        "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "657468c3a9cce4d7b7ef9197"
      }
    },
    {
      "retweetedBy": {
        "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "657468f5039119e09b0bedda"
      }
    },
    {
      "retweetedBy": {
        "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "657469296dcf5d56f8409cb8"
      }
    },
    {
      "retweetedBy": {
        "$oid": "6571f82d5f197993891520e2"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "65756f4804a28da071d69c1f"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the code calling posting comment and retweets. I am getting the id of the specific post on which i comment or repost by using props. I pass the id as Post id. Then i iterate the result with using map function on the arrays used to store comments and retweet data and display on the screen

```
const submitComment = async (postId) =>{
        setCommentBox(false)
        const request = {"postId" : postId , "commentText" : comment}
        const response = await axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/comment`, request, CONFIG_OBJ)
        if(response.status ===200){
            props.getAllPosts()
        }
    }

   
    const retweetPost = async (postId ) =>{
        const request = {"postId" : postId }

        const response = await axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/retweets`, request, CONFIG_OBJ)
        if(response.status ===200){
            props.getAllPosts()
        }
    }

    {props.postData.comments.map((comment)=>{
               return ( <div className="row mt-2">
                <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    {console.log("comments",comment)}
                <p>{comment.commentText} - {comment.commentedBy.fullName}</p>
                </div>
            </div>)
            }) }

 {props.postData.retweeter.map((retweet)=>{
               return ( <div className="row mt-2">
                <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <p>
                    {console.log("retweeter Name" , retweet.fullName)}
                    {console.log("retweeter" , retweet)}
                    r
                </p>
                </div>
            </div>)
            }) }
```

This is the function to call posts in other file. data from this function is passed to Cards class with props

```
const [allposts , setAllposts] = useState([])


    const getAllPosts= async () =>{
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/alltweets`);
        
        if(response.status ===200){
            setAllposts(response.data.posts);
        } else {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Posts not loaded'
              })
        }
    }
```